# Geometry: Making the Bleed visible together with paper/margin box

Tags: margins, geometry, paper-size

How can I draw a frame around the bleed, page and margin. I need this to fix some (margin/page) issues.

Consider the MWE below. This is already drawing a box around the page and margin. How can I make the bleed box visible?

Also is it possible to:

- Draw the bleedbox/margin box in different colors/line style?
- Not draw a box if width/height = 0 (e.g. the marginpar in MWE)?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe,
papersize={168mm,230mm}, % A5 + 2cm (2 times bleed) 
layoutsize={148mm,210mm}, % A5
layouthoffset=10mm, % Bleed
layoutvoffset=10mm, % Bleed
lmargin=20mm,
rmargin=20mm,
tmargin=20mm,
bmargin=20mm,
marginparwidth=0mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center,frame]{crop}
\begin{document}
(Type your content here.)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You pretty much want to redo the `showframe` option from `geometry`, right? You could achieve this with `background` package, I guess.